# How do I create an np array with sequences as its elements?

Tags: numpy, dataframe, sequence

I have the functions:

```
def windows(files):
    x = []
    for my_files in files:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')
        with open(os.path.join("/Users", "saqibali", "PycharmProjects", "sensorLogProject", "Data", my_files),
              'rU') as my_file:
            for d in sliding_window(sample_difference(my_file), 50, 25):
                df = df.append(d)
        x.append(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist())
    return x

def principal_components():
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    training_result = pca.fit_transform(windows(training_files))
    testing_result = pca.transform(windows(test_files))
    return training_result, testing_result
```

However, I get the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The traceback is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7       /Users/saqibali/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/FeatureSelection/FeatureSelection.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "/Users/saqibali/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/FeatureSelection/FeatureSelection.py", line 61, in <module>
principal_components()
  File "/Users/saqibali/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/FeatureSelection/FeatureSelection.py", line 56, in principal_components
training_result = pca.fit_transform(windows(training_files))
  File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 324, in fit_transform
U, S, V = self._fit(X)
  File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 346, in _fit
copy=self.copy)
  File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
 array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
```

Here's an example `df`:

```
                               time skipped         x         y         z      \
timestamp                                                                   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.055908 -0.729034  -0.645294   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.046158 -0.709091 -0.650177   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.036469 -0.699554 -0.672668   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.027908 -0.695740 -0.678070   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.027725 -0.678802 -0.697052   
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704             0 -0.037491 -0.660660 -0.719605
```

As per the comment below, I do use `pd.readcsv()` in the following function:

```
def sample_difference(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label'],
                 skipinitialspace=True)
    df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)  # Convert column type to be datetime
    df = df.set_index(['timestamp'])
    df.assign(dx=df.x.diff(), dy=df.y.diff(), dz=df.z.diff())
    return df
```

I want to have an np array with each element the np array version of the data frame from each separate file. For example, I have file one and a data frame to represent it. I want to convert that to an np array and add that to the final np array as its own element. Then, I would do the same for each file. How can I do this?

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen? Please include the whole traceback (and if possible) copy & pastable inputs (maybe some sample `df`s).

Comment: i feel like alot of your problems could be solved by just using `pd.read_csv` or if its not a csv, use another type of `pd.read_` and slice off x,y,z into a matrix

Comment: I edited the question for both of you.

Comment: Now that you have the information you needed, is it possible to help me out a bit?

Comment: In the first function `windows` I believe you need to return an array so `return np.array(x)` or in sample differences `return df[['x','y','z']].as_matrix()`

Comment: Also if you want a user to see a comment you need to tag them in it like this @dirtysocks45

Comment: I get the same error when I `return np.array(x)` @djk47463